# C# Why Method HtmlDocument.GetElementById matchs tag's attribute name?

Tags: c#, getelementbyid, dom

```
HtmlDocument.GetElementById("$id")
```

I want to use this method to get the element with `$id`, but it matches a `meta` tag with an attribute which has same value as `$id`.

HtmlDocument is like this：

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="description" content="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="description"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried to get tag `div` with id of "description":

```
HtmlElement elem = doc.GetElementById("description");
```

But I got `meta` instead of `div`. Why is the `meta` tag matching?

Comment: It looks like you are running into [this](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200802/beware_of_id_and_name_attribute_mixups_when_using_getelementbyid_in_internet_explorer/). Welcome to IE

Comment: @StuartLC might be right here. The C# implementation of [GetElementById](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=jscript#code-snippet-1) is in a shared library which is also used by JScript, which was the js engine used by IE when that article was published. Assuming it still hasn't been fixed, that could be the same problem you are running into now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why**? [Here is an official reference from Microsoft:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536437.aspx) getElementById method: Returns a reference to the first object with the specified value of the ID **or** NAME attribute.

**Solution**: You should avoid name attrib in the body so you can reference tags by id if you use myHtmlDocument.Body.All[id] formula as sharique ansari mentioned.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
HtmlDocument HtmlDocument = webBrowser1.Document;
MessageBox.Show(HtmlDocument.Body.All["description"].TagName);
```

Hope This Helps?